# React not rendering components to DOM

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware there are other questions with similar titles, but the code is unique. I double checked what I found in those post against mine and I still can't figure out why when I add a component to the App component, to render it to the DOM, The text I did have onscreen disappears and I'm left with a white page.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./my-components/header";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.title = "BuyStuff";
    this.state = { clickCouner: 0 };
  }

  renderClickCounter() {
    return <h2>I have been clicked {this.state.clickCouner} times!</h2>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.title}</h1>
        <h3>{this.renderClickCounter()}</h3>
        <Header name="??" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from "react";

const Header = (props) => <h1>{props.title}</h1>;

export default Header;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code seems to be working just fine.

Comment: For me, the content disappears when I add the external component. Thanks now I know it isn't in the code, but maybe the way I previously close server, as I created and started the project using the same npx (create) npm(start). No additional options. I'll keep working at it. Thanks

Comment: You should include that into the question to create a [mre]. What kinda external component? Please show.

Comment: It's working 

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-dubinsky-cb16er

Comment: I'm sorry, I was referring to the Header component. Thanks I see it runs fine and nothing is wrong with the code. I just have to check what I done differently with the server or the config files. I've somewhat compared them against the previous project that was running and everything seems to be intact. Thanks again.

Comment: **Note** You're passing the `name` prop to the `Header` but using `title` inside the component.

Comment: Yes, the different file extension had something to do with it and using the correct props name definitely helped. Thanks all. You are great.

Answer (score 0):

The header is rendering but with an empty content. You set a `name` prop, and display a `title`. BTW `h2` can't be a child of `h3`.